# Deleting edges and face problem

Tags: edges

[image]

I simply want to delete those things that are selected, edges and face. I removed doubles, tried every option which offers when I press "x" but with some options nothing happens, and with some all mesh above this gets messed up.

Comment: deselect the horizintal edge that also belongs to the upper face, then x > delete edges. The x delete command is contextsensitive to your current selection mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Select only the edges you want to delete and <kbd>Right-Click</kbd> > *Dissolve Edges*.

You have one excess edge selected, which forms top of a face

Comment: Thanks! Clearer now!

Answer (score 4):

hit the <kbd>1</kbd> key to go to Vertex select mode. Deselect everything, tap <kbd>B</kbd> for Box select and drag box around bottom vertices to select those. 
[image]

Then hit <kbd>X</kbd> and select vertices to delete.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I understand now

Answer (score 0):

I have Blender 3.2?

For my case, I solved it by selecting that edge and deleting again and again numerous times e.g. 5-10 times per edge until it get deleted.

Hope that helps.